# Can't click button in selenium, but can click it in regular chrome tab

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to build a software solution that adds emails to my job board's newsletter by automatically typing in an email and clicking "create alert". When using regular google chrome, I am able to click the "create alert", but when using selenium's browser it doesn't let me click the button even without automation. i'm wondering if i would have to automate the process using pure javascript. Let me share the page i am having trouble with: [https://goflexboard.com/jobs/?categories[]=Manufacturing](https://goflexboard.com/jobs/?categories%5B%5D=Manufacturing)

Here I am trying to create a job alert which is a newsletter that sends recommended jobs every day. It is letting me click create alert from regular google chrome, but not from the chrome browser controlled by selenium.

I tried clicking it in regular chrome and it worked, but when i try in selenium it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?

I suppose the error is element not found?

Just add a condition to wait for the element to appear before you click it.

Sometimes the response time of browsers vary.

```
# Adjust the time as necessary
```

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
)

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/
here are different waits. the one above is an explicit wait. you can refer to this doc and use implicit wait , as it is less flaky.
explicit wait will help you diagnose if the problem is with load time.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-measure-page-load-times-selenium-sarah-elson/
here is how you can see if page load time vary for you. just if you are curious and want to learn about load times

Comment: it is returning null when i try to click the element. The issue is that i can use javascript to click the element in regular chrome browser, but trying the same javascript to click element in selenium powered chrome browser i can't click. I think the site is using bot detection

Comment: Could very well be , when you say regular chrome do you mean manually doing it in chrome?

Comment: yes i am trying to click it using javascript and it works manually in chrome, but when i try it manually in the selenium webbrowser using inspect element it doesn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: fixed the comment to have better links and more info